# Can I use an English locale setting on a Polish EEE Pad Transformer?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, languages, localization

I live in Poland, but I am primarily an English speaker and I cannot speak any Polish. I want to buy the Asus Transformer tablet from a local online store over here in Poland. Will the interface of the tablet will be in English or Polish? If it is in Polish, can I simply change to English by changing the settings or do I have to install any extra software packages or do something out of the ordinary that a normal tablet user wouldn't usually do?

Comment: I think you might end up having to ask Asus this. If you go through them directly it may even be possible to order an English model for the same price as the Polish (I've ordered PCs etc with other European setups, keyboards, power cables and so on, through the main distributor in my country a number of times with no problems).

Comment: I just got a reply from the store that I had emailed yesterday. They said they only have the transformer with its interface in Polish. Though I am sure it is trivial to change the interface to English, through some language settings.

Comment: Most Android devices ask for the display language on the first boot, it's the first question. Assuming they haven't deleted the language files, which is pretty uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the language within settings -> Language & input.  There are options for English (Canada, United Kingdom, and United States) and Polish (Polski) as well as a variety of other languages.  If it's in Polish, tap the bottom right of the tablet (the clock area), tap the top box (where the time is), tap the bottom option (Ustawienia - Settings), tap the icon that has an A in it (Jezyk i wprowadzanie danych - Language and input) and tap the top option on the right (Wybierz jezyk - Select language).  From there, you can scroll to the English option you want and tap it.

Comment: Thank You. Just got an Asus tablet for Christmas and it was in a different language (not polish or english). These instructions were very helpful.